# MySQLi prepared Conditional Statements

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have four possible variables, only one of them is required. My question is, how do I prepare a statement / construct the sql query if there parts of the query that may or not show up.

Something like this, I guess:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM dogs WHERE name = ?"
if(isset($dogid)) {
sql .= "AND WHERE id = ?";
}

}
if(isset($dogcolour)) {
sql .= "AND WHERE colour = ?";
}
```

My brain is totally broken, and I figure there has to be a better way to prepare it than using something like $dogID = "true"; in each if, and then binding it at the end with a bunch of if statements.

Comment: Leave a space before the ANDs,it comes out `WHERE name='blah'AND..` but there is nothing wrong with conditionally building the query

Comment: Yah, I don't think there's an issue with building it, but I figured there must be an easier way than doing something like $bind_params.= "s";, $bind_params .= "i"; etc., and $bind_vars .= '$id'; $bind_vars .= "$color", etc. all within the different if(){}s --

Comment: If you're bashing around with low-level `mysqli` this is the way to do it. You can simplify it by composing conditions in an array, then joining them together at the last step using `" AND "`. A better way would be to use use of a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) that comes with a robust ORM that has simplified methods for describing your filters.

Comment: thanks @tadman -- It was something very low level, and I ended up just creating a 10 line function that dumps the values into an array and foreaches through it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a dynamic mysql query using php variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15794179/create-a-dynamic-mysql-query-using-php-variables)

Answer (score 1):

Well I would define some empty value, and then check everything in database.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM dogs WHERE (IF(? = 0, 1 = 1, name = ?)) AND (IF(? = 0, 1 = 1, colour = ?))"
```

this solution has one drawback, you need to pass all parameters twice:

```
$statement->bind_param('ssss', $name, $name, $colour, $colour);
```

if name or $colour variable is 0 then `1 = 1` is executed in where statement (witch is always true). There should be posibility to pass NULL value to mysqli, however for me it doesn't work, if it work then could be possible to simplify query.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM dogs WHERE name = (IFNULL(?, name)) AND colour = (IFNULL(?, colour))"
```

Comment: That's a clever way of doing it, but probably too clever by half. I'm notes sure that will properly use indexes due to the dynamic nature of the conditions, it may require a very expensive table-scan.