# Adding search_column function to mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Is there a way to convert this query into a new function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
 WHERE COLUMN_NAME IN ('current_edition') AND TABLE_SCHEMA='db_local';
```

where `current_edition` and `db_local` are variables so it is possible to search for a column using:

```
search_column('column_name', 'database');
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a dynamic mysql query using php variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15794179/create-a-dynamic-mysql-query-using-php-variables)

Answer (score 1):

you want to return a `table` using `function` in MySQL as I know you can't, but you can use a `procedure`:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE search_column(cl_name VARCHAR(100),db_name VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN
  SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
  WHERE COLUMN_NAME like cl_name 
    AND TABLE_SCHEMA=db_name;
END;
```