# Query with dynamic variables in clause WHERE

Tags: php, mysql, sql, dynamic, mysqli

I want to create a dynamic SQL query. For example maybe at one point I only want to search by name, and in other case I want to search by name and surname. It is this posible with only sql_query filled with params?

```
 public static function test($name,$surname) {

    $db = DBInstance::getInstance();
    $mysqli = $db->getConnection();

    $sql = 'SELECT name FROM users WHERE ' .
            'name = ? AND ' .
            'surname = ?';

    /* Prepare statement */
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
    


    /* Bind parameters. Types: s = string, i = integer, d = double,  b = blob */
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $name, $surname);

    /* Execute statement */
    $stmt->execute();

    /* Fetch result to array */
    $res = $stmt->get_result();
    while ($row = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
       var_dump($row);
    }

    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your query to:

SELECT name FROM users WHERE name = ? AND surname **like** ?

and when you want to search by name then the arguments of  test($name,$surname)  will be --> test('yourname','%');

here note that % is wild card and surname in query is using "like" so at the end the query will be:

SELECT name FROM users WHERE name = 'yourname' AND surname like '%'.
What it will search is data will 'yourname' as name and any value for surname.

Now, if you want to search by name and surname then you can call the function as
--> test('yourname','yoursurname')
so the query will become:

SELECT name FROM users WHERE name = 'yourname' AND surname like 'yoursurname'.
What it will search is data will 'yourname' as name and 'yoursurname' as surname. Thus just using a single query you can solve both purpose

Comment: Thanks, I found another solution with same problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15794179/create-a-dynamic-mysql-query-using-php-variables