# SQL advanced search query for property searches

Tags: mysql, advanced-search

I am doing an advanced search query for property listing searches. I ran into a lot of obvious bugs that were eventually fixed however, it is still not pulling the results so I am wondering if someone can help me point out where the query is wrong. I want to search for property listings by city, state, property type such as vacant land or house, status such as for rent or for sale, baths, bedrooms, garage and minimum price and maximum price. this is the query as it is now. I modified it a few different ways to see which one executed it correctly but none have worked thus far. Below is an example.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table 
 WHERE aprvl = 'value' 
   and status = '$status' 
   and city LIKE '%$city%' 
   and state LIKE '%$state%' 
   and type LIKE '%$type%' 
   and beds = '$beds' 
   and bath = '$bath' 
   and garage = '$garage' 
   and price BETWEEN '$minPrice' and '$maxPrice' 
 ORDER 
    BY column DESC 
 LIMIT $start, $limit
```

Anything that you can catch here would be great help. To me it seems to be right but maybe I am missing something.

Thanks

Comment: Making a PHP dynamic query issue is already solved [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15794249/4593781)

Comment: I saw it but I don't see how it connects with what I need. I just need it to come from a simple form that has all the values via POST method. I'll take another look at the page you recommended, thank you.

Comment: Try the `OR WHERE` maybe?