# Mysql select query based on multiple user inputs

Tags: mysql, express

Currently my table have the following fields

```
id,medium(json) ,material(json),subject,category
```

I would like to perform a filter based on user inputs that is if user input is present on particular field perform a `where` sql  based on that input

minimal code

```
var sql = 'SELECT * FROM table';

    //category is present in userinput 
    if(category){
      sql+='WHERE category=category';   
    }
    //subject is present in userinput
    if(subject){
      sql+='WHERE subject=subject'
    }
    if(material){
       sql+='WHERE material=material'
     }
   if(medium){
      sql+='WHERE medium=medium'
    }

    db.query(sql,function(error,result){
         console.log(result);
    });
```

But i confused where can i put `AND` in sql query  when  any two of the user input is present or user input contains all the fields

Comment: *"Minimal code"* : well, there's no code to support the php and mysql tags, which makes this question already unclear.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Hover over the `express` tag. Its a javascript framework over node

Comment: There is more to do here than you expect. I see that the `material` and `medium` columns are JSON. So there is a whole bunch of extra stuff needed just for that column to be used in a search criteria

Comment: Let me try yr answers

Comment: I guess my answer won't work, I apparently skipped the json column thing...

Comment: Just reworked my answer completely. Didn't test yet, but I'm about to.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    var sql = 'SELECT * FROM table';
    var where = ' WHERE';

    //category is present in userinput 
    if(category){
      sql += where + ' category=category';   
      where = ' and';
    }

    //subject is present in userinput
    if(subject){
      sql += where + ' subject=subject';
      where = ' and';
    }

    if(material){
       sql += where + ' material=material';
       where = ' and';
     }

    if(medium){
      sql += where + ' medium=medium';
    }

    db.query(sql,function(error,result){
         console.log(result);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit #3:

Now, I got it right (I think :>).

```
var sql = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1';

//category is present in userinput 
if(category) {
  sql+=' AND category = category';   
}
//subject is present in userinput
if(subject) {
  sql+=' AND subject = subject'
}
if(material) {
  sql+=' AND JSON_SEARCH(material, "one", material) IS NOT NULL'
}
if(medium) {
  sql+=' AND JSON_SEARCH(medium, "one", medium) IS NOT NULL'
}
```

Care about correct quotes, please. Also, maybe it's a good idea to change the variable names so they do **NOT** correspond with the table column names. Btw. *subject* and *medium* are reserved name, better put them in backticks.

Screenshot:
[image: New screenshot]

---

Edit:

sorry I misread your question. Use JSON_EXTRACT to extract data from the json column **json_column**, suppose you have a one-dimensional json data structure like

```
{
  "category": "Test Category"
}
```

You get the idea.

```
var sql = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1';

//category is present in userinput 
if(category) {
  sql+=' AND category = category';   
}
//subject is present in userinput
if(subject) {
  sql+=' AND subject = subject'
}
if(material) {
  sql+=' AND JSON_EXTRACT(material, "$.json_column") = material'
}
if(medium) {
  sql+=' AND JSON_EXTRACT(medium, "$.json_column") = medium'
}
```

Edit #2: Added a screenshot from phpMyAdmin:
[image: pma screenshot json_extract]

Comment: Thanks for the update but i am stroing json as plain not in object represenation eg:instead of {"material":"Plastic"} i am using  this  `["plastic","paper"]`

Comment: Okay, I will adapt my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try below logic for your query get reference from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15794179/create-a-dynamic-mysql-query-using-php-variables)

```
 if(category){
              sql[] ='category=category';   
            }

            if(subject){
              sql[] ='subject=subject'
            }
            if(material){
               sql[] ='material=material'
             }
           if(medium){
              sql[] ='medium=medium'
            }
    var sql1 = 'SELECT * FROM table';

    if (index < sql.length) {
        sql1 += ' WHERE ' + sql.join(' AND ');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var sql = 'SELECT * FROM table';
var $aux = [];

//category is present in userinput 
if(category){
  $aux[] ='category=category';   
}
//subject is present in userinput
if(subject){
  $aux[]='subject=subject'
}
if(material){
   $aux[]='material=material'
 }
if(medium){
  $aux[]='medium=medium'
}

$wheres = implode(' and ', $aux);

if($wheres)
    $sql+= ' WHERE '.$wheres;

db.query(sql,function(error,result){
     console.log(result);
});
```