# Mysql filter query based on user inputs

Tags: mysql, node.js, rest, express

[My previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43634385/mysql-select-query-based-on-multiple-user-inputs) was not giving a clear idea about my problem, that is why I am asking a new question .

Here is my table structure

```
id,
subject (varchar),
category(varchar),
medium(json),
material(json),
style(json)
```

User can able to search based on the values in table fields ie if user choose only `subject` (he can select it from multiple select dropdown) query result contains rows that matches the selected items.

If user selected subject and category query result contains rows that matches the selected items and so on (in short it's a filter search like shopping websites)

The problem is I don't how I can efficiently build the MySQL query based on these inputs because some of the Mysql columns are JSON.

Here is the separate SQL query:

```
// select rows that contains subject test or test1
SELECT * 
FROM `cushbu_art` 
WHERE subject IN ('test','test1')

// select rows that contains medium is paper or food
SELECT * 
FROM `cushbu_art` 
WHERE (JSON_CONTAINS(medium, '["paper"]') 
       OR JSON_CONTAINS(medium, '["food"]'))
```

Here is a sample input with two parameters (`subject` and `medium`)

```
{
    "subject":["test","test1"],
    "medium":["paper","wood"],
    "category":"",
    "material":"",
    "style":""
}
```

Note: input and output are in JSON (REST API)

**db.js**

```
function(req, res) {
    var sql = '';

    if(req.body.subject) {
        sql+=//PREPARE SUBJECT QUERY
    }

    if(req.body.medium) {
       sql+=//PREPARE QUERY
    }

    //FINAL SQL QUERY HERE;
    db.query(sql, function(error, result) {
       console.log(result);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function(req,res){
 var sql = 'SELECT * FROM `cushbu_art`';

 //Check if only on is set
 if(req.body.subject && !req.body.medium){
  var subjectJoin=req.body.subject.join(',');
  sql+='WHERE subject IN ('+subjectJoin+')';

}

 //Check if only on is set 
if(req.body.medium && !req.body.subject){
      sql+='WHERE (JSON_CONTAINS(medium,'+req.body.medium[0]+') OR JSON_CONTAINS(medium,'+req.body.medium[1]+')';
}

if(req.body.medium && req.body.subject){

 var subjectJoin=req.body.subject.join(',');

 sql+='WHERE subject IN ('+subjectJoin+') AND (JSON_CONTAINS(medium,'+req.body.medium[0]+') OR JSON_CONTAINS(medium,'+req.body.medium[1]+')';

}

  //FINAL SQL QUERY HERE';
  db.query(sql,function(error,result){
   console.log(result);
 });

}
```