# MYSQL:filter query based on user input

Tags: mysql

Maybe this is a simple question but i am struggled to find the answer.

I am trying to implement a filter feature based on `category`,`subject` and `medium` fields value from the table `art`.

that means if user select only `category` the result will be the query 
`SELECT * FROM ART WHERE category=val`

if user select `category` and `subject` it should be  `SELECT * FROM ART WHERE category=val AND subject=val`

and so on

But i don't how i dynamically build this query one approach is write all possible combinations query and  execute based on conditions but i don't think its a good approach

Comment: Can you share the code of whatever attempt you made to resolve this issue?

Comment: I mentiond my approach in question

Comment: Did you write any code for that?

Comment: I disagree with you that using separate queries for different types of searches is a bad approach.  Typically if the structure of the query needs to be different, you should use a separate query.  You _might_ be able to do something like have `subject=subject` when the user does not select a subject, but this suggestion gets second place to my first idea.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya not writed any code

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen are you saying write different query for each condition?

Comment: Thant's what you need to do first. You need to make an attempt to resolve the issue by yourself and come back here if you face any specific issue in that. To help you to start with, you need to create SQL query using string concatenation based on the user's selection. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43649925/mysql-filter-query-based-on-user-inputs. You can improvise this by using parameterized query.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Your comments about needing to show code are right, but the rest of what you are suggesting, while good, is off topic for this question.

Comment: @Jabaa Yes, I would probably use separate queries for each condition.  This isn't evil and even if you find a way to use just one query, it could easily break down the road should your logic change.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen is it solve with mysql when case ??

Comment: I'm afraid a complete answer cannot be given now because you showed no code.  Yes, I could give you a raw MySQL query which would do what you want, but that wouldn't match with your Node.js tag.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen With due respect, I am not sure which part of suggesting an approach is off topic. I am not a node.js person but in C# that's how I handle such cases and that's why I tried to suggest.

Comment: Its a typo  now tags are corrected

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen could you give example raw query??

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Parameters control the data being fed into a single fixed query, they do not control the structure of that query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql=" SELECT * FROM ART where 1=1   ";

if(!empty($category) {
    $sql.=" and category= $value";
}

if(!empty($subject) {
  $sql.=" and subject= $value";
}

if(!empty($medium) {
   $sql.=" and medium= $value";
}
```

where 1=1 is just to keep the syntax correct else you need to have some login to add where accordingly as you can't add where in all three checks (will make incorrect sql string).

**Read about sql injection. Use parameter binding to add parameter, this is just for you to get an idea, this will work but is vulnerable to sql injection**

Comment: I just struggled with this `where 1=1 ` let me try

Answer (score 0):

Try all the filters in the where condition with OR not AND as shown below

```
SELECT * FROM ART WHERE category=val OR subject=val OR medium=val;
```