# php prepared statement multiple possible querys

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm using prepared statement for MySQLi PHP which is all working. However, the application that I'm using this in has 108 different possible statements all very similar that can be run either without condition:

```
select * from table1
```

or with

```
select * from table 1 where user_level = 1)
```

The question that I'm asking: Is there a way that I can create the statement that covers all possibilities such as

```
select * from table 1 where user_level = {special input}
```

that will give the same outcome as

```
select * from table1
```

Otherwise I'm looking at a lot of repetition.

Comment: For what you have described the solution is simple if the variable is empty take all if not use the variable.

Comment: Have you tried with `IFNULL`?

Comment: I am not sure what it has to do with PHP or mysqli. I think your question is about composing SQL query.

Comment: May be worth looking at [Create a dynamic mysql query using php variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15794179/create-a-dynamic-mysql-query-using-php-variables).  BUT please use prepared statements as the accepted answer doesn't

Comment: I understand that what I'm trying to stop is me writing out multiple if statements for things like if user level is set or not. what I'm looking for is a statement that can be written so that the same query can be used for multiple statements

Answer (score 0):

You would use parameter binding. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php.